# Specific lay-out for every content-type

Tags: nodes, theming

Is it possible to change the layout for a content type through CSS? How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment of the OP (Niels) I changed my answer:

Each content type page will have a different class (node-type-*CONTENTTYPE*) associated to the BODY element of your HTML.

So you can add to your CSS file:

```
body.node-type-mycontenttype1 img { border-color: red; }
body.node-type-mycontenttype2 img { border-color: yellow; }
```

---

Original answer:

Wich version of Drupal do you use?

For Drupal 7:

You can use a different template for each node of different content type by creating a template:

/site/all/themes/*YOUR THEME*/templates/node--*CONTENTYPE*.tpl.php

You can read on [Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) to know which template you can create.

For the CSS, I suggest you to put everything in your main CSS file and not use a different CSS for each content type.

Comment: Thank you, I only want to change some text-layout and not the whole theme. For example some Borders around images, text-align,...

Comment: I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also for different page layout (not only node layout) for different node types you have to add template suggestions to your theme, then you can style in with CSS.

**For Drupal 6**
add this code  to **template.php**

```
<?php
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
   $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-'. str_replace('_', '-', $vars['node']->type);
  }
}
?>
```

Then make different files for any content type you have and layout them as you wish

- page-blog.tpl.php *for blog content type*
- page-news.tpl.php *for news content type* ... etc.

**Similar for Drupal 7**

```
<?php
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. str_replace('_', '--', $vars['node']->type);
  }
}
?>
```

Then make different files for any content type you have:

- page--blog.tpl.php *for blog content type*
- page--news.tpl.php *for news content type* ... etc.

Comment: We were writing at the same time.
Based on your comments, ignore my answer.
Just Follow FR6 Instructions

Comment: Thank you for the answers guy. I was trying to fix this but I'm not able to do it and i Don't know what I do wrong.
I'm just a beginner but I want to learn more.
I located this CSS file ((drupalfolder)/modules/system/system.theme.css) and i wrote this in it:


body.packages field-item even p
{
 font-weight:bold;
}

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Maybe this could help you guys. http://nielsjansen.be/drupal

Comment: Hi! Consider using Context Module. You'll be able to add classes based on node type, taxonomy term, path....Here is great video podcast http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode38